# How create a service in Angular 7 that use FS module to list files from directory?

Tags: node.js, angular, electron, observable, readfile

I´m coding an app based on Node v10.13.0, Electron 3.0.7 & Angular 7.

A service is in charge of file procesing, a function named(**listFiles**) read and return an array of filenames contained in a directory.

```
    listFiles(path):Observable<string[]>{
    this.files_in_directories = [];

    return of(this.fs.readdir(path, function(err, items) {  
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
      }
      for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
          this.files_in_directories.push(items[i]);
          console.log(items[i]);
      }
      return this.files_in_directories;
    }.bind(this)));
  }
```

My code is based on Angular Guide: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#observable-heroservice

In the component, the service is called:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.getScripts('Project');
  }

  getScripts(project){
    this.generalService.listFiles(this.config.location.datastore+'\\'+project).subscribe(files=>{
      this.scripts = files;
      this.cdref.detectChanges();
    });        
  }
```

When this code is executed, the files are readed but never returned, as an Observable, instead an **undefined** value is obtained(See the image):
[Undefined Values Debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVr0X.jpg)

I'm a little bit lost how to proceed from this point foward, the files in the directory are correctly listed.[File Listed in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXJUh.jpg)

I belive that problem comes from returning the array inside a callback. Any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

@NishKal Kashyap, you are rigth men, before see you response I modified the code in the service to read the files in the directory synchronously. And worked just fine, thankyou for the sugestion.

```
listFiles(path):Observable<string[]>{
    this.files_in_directories = [];
    this.fs.readdirSync(path).forEach(file => {
      this.files_in_directories.push(file);
    });

    return of(this.files_in_directories);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You identified the problem correctly, perhaps modify your code like this:

```
listFiles(path):Observable<string[]>{
this.files_in_directories = [];

this.fs.readdir(path, function(err, items) {  
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
  for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
      this.files_in_directories.push(items[i]);
      console.log(items[i]);
  }
});

of(this.files_in_directories);
```